# how to externalise url in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a spring security file in which I have below configuration.

```
<security:session-management
            invalid-session-url="/login.jsp">
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" />
    </security:session-management>
```

I want to externalise value of `invalid-session-url`.
I have configured `xyz.properties` file.
when I use placeholder as invalid-session-url="${login.url}",  It throws exception

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: url must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65) ~[spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy.<init>(SimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy.java:26) ~[spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpConfigurationBuilder.createSessionManagementFilters(HttpConfigurationBuilder.java:277) ~[spring-security-config-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpConfigurationBuilder.<init>(HttpConfigurationBuilder.java:128) ~[spring-security-config-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.createFilterChain(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:119) ~[spring-security-config-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.parse(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:83) ~[spring-security-config-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:90) ~[spring-security-config-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Apparently the login.url does not resolve to '/login.jsp'. How did you load the property file in spring? Furthermore, I would check for trivial errors such as typos in the property name or value.

Comment: thanks for response Nils.I have loaded property file in spring. I am able to read other properties while is used in "value" attribute of property tag. eg <property name="something" value="${something}">. here i am able read this value. but when I want read value in above url. it throws exception